# CSS changes being erased after ANT ALL

Tags: css, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm creating a theme and store from scratch, currently every single time I do a `ant all` in console every change I've done into the style.css of the theme is erased and goes back to standard CSS.

Any ideas how can I keep my CSS changes even if I do a `ant all/ant clean all`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a `style.scss` or `style.less` file somewhere? Sounds like you have a CSS pre-processor of some sort.

Comment: There's a style.less in the Theme with the following lines:import "../../../lib/ybase-0.1.0/less/ybase.less";
import "../../../lib/ybase-0.1.0/less/addons.less";
import "variables.less";

Comment: Then you'll need to make your CSS changes in the `.less` file. The `.css` file is simply the processed version of the `.less` file and will be blown away when you run your build scripts. Read up on http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 2):

> The yacceleratorstorefront extension template provides a process for building a responsive website front end that supports LESS.

Build process will generate a _ui folder that contains the appropriate JS and CSS styling. This process can be started either through Ant or Grunt.

Modify any required storefront files in the _ui-src folder and then generate the _ui folder using ant or grunt build is the recommended approach. **Kindly make changes to js or less files which are available in _ui-src folder and build will generate the respective js or css changes in _ui folder.**

Check [this](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8ac7e55f86691014a6a9c4f7224649a0.html) for more details.